# Spacing in align environment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, align

I am familiar with the `\flushright` and `\hfill` commands for positioning text to the far right of the page. However throughout my document I am using the terms `(x\rightarrow\infty)` on many lines and I wish to send them all to the far right of the page so that they line up nicely. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non)working example so that we can see exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Hi is this what you mean ? \begin{align*}
g(x)&\sim x^\rho\ell(x)\qquad(x\rightarrow\infty)\end{align*}

Comment: And i am trying to get the (x\rightarrow\infty) to the far right of the page

Answer (score 3):

If you're using unnumbered equation-like environments, as would seem to be the case, you could use (abuse?!) the `\tag{$ ... $}` and `\tag*{$ ... $}` macros to place the `x\to\infty` material at the far-right edge of the line. The first macro, `\tag`, surrounds its argument in parentheses, making it look a little bit like a substitute equation number; the second macro, `\tag*`, does not provide parentheses.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
g(x)&\sim x^\rho\ell(x) \tag{$x\to\infty$}\\
g(x)&\sim x^\rho\ell(x) \tag*{$x\to\infty$}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the `flalign*` environment and the `mathllap`  command (from `mathtools`). I also propose a second way of writing, which is better, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bothsides]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
 \begin{flalign*}
 & & g(x)&\sim x^\rho\ell(x) & & \mathllap{(x\rightarrow\infty)}
 \end{flalign*}

\[ g(x)\sim_{\infty} x^\rho\ell(x) \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hmmm im having problems getting the mathtools package?

Comment: Which distribution do you have installed? Is it old? There have been some substantial modifications on the organisation of this package last summer.

Comment: I have Latex 3 if thats what you mean? and im getting this message "Not a local package repository"

Comment: No,, latex3 has nothing to see here. What I mean is: do you have TeX Live, MiKTeX, MacTeX?

Comment: er miktex i think

Comment: OK. Run MiKTeX Package Manager (`MPM`) as administrator. You will have a list of all available and installed packages (with the dates). Check the status of `mathtools`. If it is not installed, ask to install it.

Comment: I tried that but it says unknown archive file size?

Comment: When did you do the last update? You should probably `synchronise` the repository (menu `Repository`).

Comment: Thanks I got it to work! by any chance do you know how to format a page to be 42 lines long?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to do some calculations by yourself? Take a look at the description of the `heightrounded` option of the `geometry` package (§ 5.3, p.8 of the documentation).